# How to write a command line script (not ant task) to generate a checkstyle report?

Tags: java, scripting, command-line, ant, checkstyle

I got how to write an ant task to generate a report like [this](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/maven/how-do-i-generate-a-checkstyle-code-style-report-for-a-site/how-do-i-generate-a-checkstyle-code-style-report-for-a-site-03.gif) but I want to use just a command line script and not ant to generate this. How can I do it?

Comment: What's the reason for avoiding Ant? It would be the obvious tool for the job.

Comment: For bunch of process reasons I can't use ant and I am not in a position to change that decision. There must be a simple way to do this through command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distributions of Checkstyle include a [command-line interface](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/cmdline.html).  If you can't use your Ant task, that might be the next option to look in to.

> Run checkstyle with configuration file
>   docs/sun_checks.xml on all java files
>   in a directory
>
> `java
>   com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Main
>   -c docs/sun_checks.xml
>        -r src/`

Comment: I tried that, it only outputs to an xml file, I want a pretty html output. There must be some way to give it a specific xml stylesheet.

Comment: @wrick - I don't think there is.  You could post-process the xml though (this is what's done when Checkstyle is used from Ant).  Either with 'xsltproc' if you're on a unix system or perhaps msxml on windows.  Another possibility is to paste into the XML a reference to the stylesheet you want, and let the browser apply it.